# Forbiden rule with a condition in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have this rule to forbidden URLs that not contain "view-ports" string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !view-ports
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

How can I change it to forbidden **only** URLs with the condition above and not end with a "/"

So for example the URLs below should be allowed:

```
https://www.sample.com/list/
https://www.sample.com/list/cities/
https://www.sample.com/view-ports?q=832
https://www.sample.com/data/view-ports?l=131
.
.
.
```

but for example the URLs below should be forbidden:

```
https://www.sample.com/list
https://www.sample.com/list/cities
https://www.sample.com/q=1312324
https://www.sample.com/data/l=131
.
.
.
```

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !view-ports
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

It works but the problem is it forbiddens the root itself also:

```
https://www.sample.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer by myself.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !view-ports
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

That solved the root directory 403 error.